Why can I move the variable twice?
I have the following code, and I can move unique pointer variable several times.
Why is it allowed? Also, what is the difference between an arg with && and without &&?
#include <iostream>

std::unique_ptr<int> make_obj(int v) {
  return std::make_unique<int>(v);
}

void print(std::unique_ptr<int> &&v) { // <- why && allows multiple moves?
  std::cout << *v << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  auto val = make_obj(1);
  print(std::move(val)); // the first time move
  int a = 0;
  print(std::move(val)); // the second time move
}



Because std::move doesn't move, it casts a variable to an rvalue reference. If you want to move a variable, you should move it to an object, not cast to an rvalue reference.

If you changed void print(std::unique_ptr<int> &&v) to void print(std::unique_ptr<int> v) then you really would be moving twice.

Moving typically happens when you invoke a move constructor or a move assignment operator, std::move enables that (by casting to an rvalue reference) but you still have to somehow invoke some code that does a move.

std::move doesn't actually move anything. See this answer that has another example which will make your example more clear.

And argument with && is an rvalue reference, an argument without is not. Seems like you need to learn about rvalue references.

You probably don't need to fully understand rvalue references because mostly the only time you will use them is if you are writing a move constructor or move assignment operator. It's because you tried to use an rvalue reference in your print function that you got yourself confused.

std::move should have been called std::pretend_to_be_a_temporary_so_it_can_be_moved_from, but thats too long. Nothing in your code does the actual move.

In addition, even though we usually say that we "move objects", it is quite misleading. Objects in C++ cannot be moved (relocated), only their content can (whatever this is), and only for certain types.

Also, unique_ptr is specifically specified to be well behaved when moved from. The pointer it holds is turned into a nullptr, similar to a default constructed object. If moved again, nothing in particular happens, and it is not an error.
